# It's getting a little crowded in the achievements dialog

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

... when you're gaining or losing reputation on multiple sites on a single day:

[image]

In the past, after 12 icons or so, the rest would continue on the next line. Now there isn't even room to show the last one (English Language Learners).

Tested with the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS.

Comment: Geez, just stop being so active all over the place. :)

Comment: I'm even too busy to draw a freehand circle...

Comment: Looks like they've even squished as the padding is gone between them.

Comment: Those -1's don't look very welcoming ...

Comment: I've retracted some of them, they were just cast *for science*.

Comment: Happy for the negatives... Show off −_

Comment: I've added another one for you.

Comment: They forgot to make it Overflow. o_O