# New privilege tracker - 'Track the next one' banner misplaced when you've also earned a new badge

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

I'll admit that this is a rare case, but when you've earned a new privilege *and* a badge you've tracked, the dark blue 'banner' which contains the 'Track the next one' button seems to be positioned too high, leaving an 'empty' gray line at the bottom of the widget. I suspect this happens because the height of the badge tracker widget in this case is higher than would be normally.

[image]

Tested with the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Mojave.

Comment: Fix: stop earning so many things! ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution for [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309665/295232) [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304538/295232)...

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to this other question: ["You've earned (badge)" panel layouts are broken](/q/316061)